# Python & Arduino commands continuously

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, pyserial, arduino-uno

I am trying to set up a python script which needs to send several commands individually to my Arduino and from that, read all the output it creates. 
I have an Arduino script, which responds to simple string commands (like MA 3 etc.) with either OK, ERR or a value (depending if I am setting up the Arduino or if I am measuring on the component connected to the board).

For example:

```
ser = serial.Serial("COM6", 115200)

ser.write('SA 50000')
ser.write('SM 0')
ser.write('SI 0')
ser.write('SF 500')
ser.write('MA 3')

while True:
    print ser.readline()
```

So I want this code to set up the parameters (the first 4 write statements), start meassuring (the last write) and then print until there is nothing more coming from the component. 
I know that the while statement doesn't close down at any point, but it is not my problem. My problem is that the script won't send my parameters the way they are written now, unless I put the in the while statement, which causes the Arduino to redo the parameter all the time.

Can anyone help me? I am fairly new to the whole pyserial and talking to Arduinos. My Arduino script works (I tested it in the Arduino monitor and if I put my statements in the while loop, it prints them).

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to send newlines?

Comment: Can you also provide relevant sections of your arduino code, this problem could also be there :)

Comment: Ignacio, can you give me an example as to how you would set a newline?

Comment: Windwarrior: The arduino is a combined perl and Arduino script, which is not one I have written myself but a friend of mine has. It works fine, so my problem is 100% within my python script. It is a matter of sending several commands and then read all the output those commands generate.

Comment: you can send a newline like so: ser.write('SA 500000\n'), the \n part is a newline. Other possibilities is that data gets lost because your arduino is not fast enough in processing, but the Arduino buffer size is 64 bytes, and above writes dont add up to 64 bytes total. Personally I am more convinced in the problem being some weird condition with the arduino code then the python you provided.

Comment: I would almost bet its the lack of newlines ...